# how to search for strings wtihin json files on Mac Sierra

Tags: json, macos

I am trying to search for a string across files in a Mac.  Sierra v10.12.5.  Using the finder, I search for files of type 'json', then using the '+' for advanced search features, I select 'contents' and my string in the textbox.  Nothing is returned.  If I change the file extension from .json to .txt, the files containing the string in the textbox are returned.  So this seems isolated to files of type .json

Today a visit to the genius bar confirmed what I saw.  However, the 'genius' told me that's all he could tell me about the subject.  I took his response as code for "you found a bug, too bad"  He said to search the web to find an unsupported solution.  Unfortunately, I haven't found a workaround.  Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This question is better asked on https://superuser.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

For a file to show up in Spotlight search results, there needs to be a Spotlight importer which can read that type of file and index it. macOS ships with importers for a number of common file formats (such as `.txt` and `.pdf`), but there is no default importer for `.json` files, since there isn't really any standard way of opening and viewing them.

If you wanted, though, [you could write an importer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/WritingAnImp.html).